# Aysnc call back to UI Thread

Tags: c++, asynchronous, windows, callback

My main DLL is a .Net one that has an async running method and fires an event when it's done:

```
public class LicenceVerifier
{

    private readonly ILicence _licence;
    private readonly int _programkey;

    public delegate void LicencedCheckedEventHandler(object sender, LicenceVerifierResultArgs args);
    public event LicencedCheckedEventHandler LicencedChecked;


    public LicenceVerifier(int programKey)
    {
        _programkey = programKey;
        _licence = GetLicensing();
    }

    public void IsValidLicenceAsync()
    {

        new Task(() =>
        {
            LicenceVerifierResult valid = LicenceVerifierResult.NotAvailable;

            if (_licence != null)
                valid = _licence.IsValid(_programkey);

            LicencedChecked(this, new LicenceVerifierResultArgs(valid));

        }).Start();

    }

.....
}
```

Now I have a C++ API for our C++ and VB6 applications.  I'm registering here to the .Net `LicensedCheckedEventHandler` to get a callback to the C++ API.

In the C++ API callback method, I post a message to a created window to get out of the worker thread back to the UI thread and then call back to the C++/VB6 applications.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#include "PublicHeader\Licensing.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace XxxX::Licensing;
using namespace std;


#define WM_LICENSING_RESULT     (WM_APP + 1001)

LRESULT CALLBACK RedirectWndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

long lCallbackAddress;
void(*callBackFunction)(int);


enum CallbackType {
    UNKNOWN,
    C,
    VB
};


public ref class LicenceVerifierCallback
{

public:

    HWND m_hWnd;
    CallbackType m_Type;

    //Callback from .NET dll
    void handler(System::Object^ sender, LicenceVerifierResultArgs^ e)
    {
        PostMessage(m_hWnd, WM_LICENSING_RESULT, convertResult(e->Result), (CallbackType)m_Type);
    };

    int convertResult(LicenceVerifierResult verifierResult)
    {
        if(verifierResult == LicenceVerifierResult::Available)
            return 0;

        return 1;
    };

};



void RegisterRedirectWnd(wchar_t szClassName[])
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)szClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = RedirectWndProc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;

    RegisterClassEx (&wc);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK RedirectWndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if(message == WM_LICENSING_RESULT)
    {
        if((CallbackType)lParam == VB)
        {
            typedef void ( *FUNCPTR) (int iResult);

            FUNCPTR vbCallBackFunction;

            vbCallBackFunction = (FUNCPTR)lCallbackAddress;
            vbCallBackFunction(wParam);

        }    

        if((CallbackType)lParam == C)
            callBackFunction(wParam);
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

//Create a window to be able to receive messages
HWND CreateMessageRetriever()
{
    RegisterRedirectWnd(L"Licensing");
    return CreateWindow(L"Licensing", NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
};


void IsLicenseValid(int iPrgKey, CallbackType type)
{

    HWND hwnd = CreateMessageRetriever();

    LicenceVerifierCallback^ callback = gcnew LicenceVerifierCallback();

    callback->m_hWnd  = hwnd;
    callback->m_Type = type;

    //The .Net object that processes the actual licensing check async
    LicenceVerifier^ licenceVerifier = gcnew LicenceVerifier(iPrgKey);
    licenceVerifier->LicencedChecked += gcnew LicenceVerifier::LicencedCheckedEventHandler(callback, &LicenceVerifierCallback::handler);
    licenceVerifier->IsValidLicenceAsync();
}

// Entry point: Call from vb6 application
void __stdcall CheckLicenseAsyncVb(int iPrgKey, int cbAddress)
{
    lCallbackAddress = cbAddress;
    IsLicenseValid(iPrgKey, VB);
}

 // Entry point: Call from c++ application
void __stdcall Licensing::CheckLicenseAsyncC(int iPrgKey, void(*callbackFunc)(int))
{
    callBackFunction = callbackFunc;
    IsLicenseValid(iPrgKey, C);
};


//Notifies the backend that the application got closed and the licence can be releases
void __stdcall Licensing::NotifyApplicationClosed(int iPrgKey)
{
    LicenceVerifier^ licenceVerifier = gcnew LicenceVerifier(iPrgKey);
    licenceVerifier->ApplicationClosed();
};
```

I'm not that familiar with C++ and wonder if the code looks okay and if the way it's done is okay as well. I have to mention that using COM was not an option.  Any further suggestions and corrections are highly welcome and appreciated.